# Are pre-fab kegerators modifiable?

Tags: kegerator

I am considering options for kegerators... on a budget.  I have scoped out Craigslist, and I have seen a few pre-fabricated kegerators (not that I'm sold on going that route).  Obviously, the one-tap jobbers are more affordable than multi-tap.

Does anyone know if it's possible to replace the column on one of those, so that I can switch up to a multiple-tap system in the future?

Comment: We bought one for the office, from what I remember the tower had a sort of twisting, locking mechanism to keep it in place. Presumably if you found a multi-tap tower with the same locking mechanism it would work. Is there some standard on the base of towers? That would be a good thing to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The top cap of the tower is removable (at least on every tower I've ever seen). There is a piece that replaces the cap and adds a few inches to the tower's height. The result is your original single faucet with new faucets slightly above and to either side, like |* . *|.  The existing tower will need to be able to accommodate the two additional beer lines, and you may need to implement something to make sure cold air is going up into the tower to prevent foaming, but the answer is yes.

I Googled "Draft Tower Extension" and found several options, including this one at Northern Brewer. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it a few ways.

1) Add an extra tower shank, like this one: http://www.ontariobeerkegs.com/product_p/tower-shank.htm

2) Replace the entire tower: http://www.ontariobeerkegs.com/Dual_Tap_Stainless_Steel_Beer_Tower_p/2tower%20tap.htm

Or, depending on the kegerator, you could add a second tower.